# Play Framework 2.2.x recover flatmap

Tags: java, playframework, akka, playframework-2.2

I want to recover my promise and return delegate.call(context) from it, but i can only return SimpleResult.

```
public class Authenticate extends Action<Authentication> {
    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> call(final Context context) throws Throwable {
        WSRequestHolder holder = WS.url(...);
        final Promise<Response> promise = holder.get();
        Promise<SimpleResult> result = promise.flatMap(new Function<Response, Promise<SimpleResult>>() {
            @Override
            public Promise<SimpleResult> apply(Response response) throws Throwable {
                JsonNode user = response.asJson().path("response");
                context.args.put("user", user);
                return delegate.call(context);
            }
        }).recover(new Function<Throwable, SimpleResult>() {
            @Override
            public SimpleResult apply(Throwable e) {
                /* cant return delegate.call(context); from here */
                return redirect(routes.Application.index());
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Maybe there are other standard and better ways to store userinfo before method calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution you posted is not a good solution, you should never, ever use Await.result when doing asynchronous programming, you risk causing deadlocks and massive performance issues.

We need to add a `recoverWith` method to the Play promise API, but until that happens, you can do this (using JDK8 syntax for brevity):

```
public class Authenticate extends Action<Authentication> {
  public Promise<SimpleResult> call(final Context context) throws Throwable {
    Promise<SimpleResult> result = WS.url(...).get();
    Promise<SimpleResult> result = promise.flatMap( response -> {
      JsonNode user = response.asJson().path("response");
      context.args.put("user", user);
      return delegate.call(context);
    }).map(Promise::pure).recover( e -> {
      return delegate.call(ontext)(routes.Application.index());
    }).flatMap(a -> a);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Basically, the above unflattens the `Promise<SimpleResult>` into `Promise<Promise<SimpleResult>>` by mapping with `Promise::pure`, then you can recover returning `Promise<SimpleResult>`, then you it flattens the promise of a promise by flatMapping with the identity function.

Comment: Would you mind posting this answer in Java 7 syntax as well, since that would help for people like me who haven't kept ourselves up to date with the new syntax

Comment: response -> { ... } translates to new Function<Response, SimpleResult> { public SimpleResult apply(Response response) { ... } }. Learn the JDK8 syntax, we'll be migrating all the Play docs to JDK8 syntax very soon, IDEs have already started doing code folding of anonymous classes to look like JDK8 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem:

```
WSRequestHolder holder = WS.url(...)
final Promise<Response> userPromise = holder.get();
Promise<SimpleResult> result = Promise.promise(new Function0<Response>() {
    @Override
    public Response apply() throws Throwable {
        Timeout timeout = new Timeout(2000);
        Future<Response> future = userPromise.wrapped();                
        Response response = Await.result(future, timeout.duration());   
        return response;
    }
}).flatMap(new Function<Response, Promise<SimpleResult>>() {
    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> apply(Response response) throws Throwable {
        try {
            JsonNode userInfo = response.asJson();
            context.args.put("user", userInfo);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }   
        return delegate.call(context);
    }               
});
return result;
```